# App built using Nw.js freezes on using window.print( ) on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, node-webkit, nw.js, nwjs

OS : Mac OS X

NW.js version (latest 0.20, tried from 0.14 to latest)

```
Issue: 
Application freezes(UI becomes unresponsive) after doing following steps:
  - Open application
  - Use functionality which trigger code "window.print()", print dialog comes up. User may print/cancel it.
  - Keep application idle for some time(3-5 mins) and now app freezes(Rendered process freezes and UI becomes unresponsive).
```

Raised issue on Nw.js forum as well:
https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/5020

Anyone has faced such issue? Any hints on troubleshooting such problems?

Comment: What kind of nwjs version are you using. Are you able to use the developer tools?